# Compilation error when using EXTFLD to define an array as subfield of a data structure

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to define an array as a subfield of a DS by referring to an external table using EXTNAME and EXTFLD. But it results in a compilation error.

```
dcl-ds P_IAC3002L                          extname('IAC3002_L') qualified template;
  LISTROWNumber                            extfld('LISTROWNBR');                   
  WorkTitle                                extfld('WORKTITLE');                    
  OriginalWorkTitle                        extfld('WRKTITLEOR');                   
  TypeOfWorkTitle                          extfld('WRKTITLETY');                   
  TitleTypeDescription                     extfld('TITLEDESC');                    
  OriginalVersionInd                       extfld('WRKORGIND');                    
  OriginalVersionIndDescription            extfld('WRKORGDESC');                   
  Role                                     extfld('ROLE' );                        
  RoleDescription                          extfld('ROLEDESC');                     
  StatusOfWork                             extfld('WRKSTS' );                      
  WorkStatusDescription                    extfld('WRKSTSDESC');                   
  WorkKey                                  extfld('WORKKEY');                      
  WorkTitleNumber                          extfld('WRKTITLENO');                   
  WorkMatchIndicator                       extfld('WRKMATCHIN');                   
  WorkCCIndicator                          extfld('WRKCCIND');                     
  OtherTitlesExist                         extfld('OTHTITLIND');                   
  WorkIsReferenced                         extfld('WRKISREF');                     
  WorkIsActive                             extfld('WRKISACT');                     
  AgreementExceptionExists                 extfld('PAGEXCEP');         
  PublisherReferences                      extfld('PUBREFS') dim(500); 
end-ds;
```

Above is the DS.

Below is the Error:

```
 PublisherReferences                      extfld('PUBREFS') dim(500);   
======>    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                                                        
*RNF0518 20 a      012900  Length of item PUBLISH... is less than 1; length defaults  
                           to 1.
```

The table definition is rather straight forward:

```
      Field                         Field                             
   Text                          Name     Type Length  Dec  Loc    
 List Row Number                 LISTROWNBR S      3    0     1    
 Work Title                      WORKTITLE  A     90          4    
 Work Original Title             WRKTITLEOR A     90         94    
 Type of Work Title              WRKTITLETY A      2        184    
 Title Type Description          TITLEDESC  A     60        186    
 Original/version Indicato       WRKORGIND  A      3        246    
 Work Original Indicator D       WRKORGDESC A     60        249    
 Role                            ROLE       A     10        309    
 Role Description                ROLEDESC   A     60        319    
 Status Of Work                  WRKSTS     S      1    0   379    
 Work Status Description         WRKSTSDESC A     60        380    
 Work Key Number                 WORKKEY    S     11    0   440 
 Work Title Sequence Numbe       WRKTITLENO S      7    0   451 
 Work Match Indicator            WRKMATCHIN A      1        458 
 Work Counterclaim Indicat       WRKCCIND   A      1        459 
 Other Titles Exist              OTHTITLIND A      1        460 
 No of none Wsm                  NONONEWSM  S      3    0   461 
 Work has Trigger                HASTRIGGER A      1        464 
 Work Is Referenced              WRKISREF   A      1        465 
 Work Is Active                  WRKISACT   A      1        466 
 Agreement Exception Exist       PAGEXCEP   A      1        467 
 Work Number Cross Referen       PUBREFS    A     20        468
```

Can somebody help on why this wont compile ?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other errors?  It would seem that `PUBREFS`  wasn't found... double check your spelling.

Comment: Check that the instance of  the `IAC3002_L` file being found by the compiler includes `PUBREFS`.  Sounds like a *LIBL issue where it's not finding the right version.

Comment: @CHARLES, I tried hardcoding the library like this :  dcl-ds P_IAC3002L                          extname('THEPAV/IAC3002_L') qualified template; still it doesnt work. THEPAV is the correct library.

Comment: @charles please believe me when I say this, but the program compiles fine if the dimension of the array is declared less than 21. If it is greater than 20, this compiler error comes up! Any clue why that might be  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, your last comment provides the answer...

You can't take a char(20) from a file and redefine it bigger than 20 bytes.

RPG is willing to treat char(20) as char(1) dim(20).

What are you trying to accomplish with dim(500)?

**EDIT**

try doing what you're trying to do like so:

```
dcl-ds P_IAC3002L extname('IAC3002_L') qualified template;
end-ds;

dcl-ds myWorkDs qualified template;
   LISTROWNumber like(p_iac3002l.LISTROWNBR);
   ....
   PublisherReferences like(p_iac3002l.PUBREFS) dim(500);
end-ds;
```

Comment: I don't understand. This DS holds various attribute values of a "work" and a work can have upto 500 "PublisherReferences" each of length 20 chars. That is why I am defining it with a dimension of 500. P_IAC3002L(50).PublisherReferences(450) should be able to store the 450th publisherrefernce of the 50th work in the DS Array. Thats the idea. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: that does work. Thank you so much! But one other issue that I come across is that i cant seem to declare "WorkReferences                           like(P_IAC3002L.WORKREF) dim(10);" before any of the fields declared using extfld. When I do that, the field declared afterwards with EXTFLD throws a compilation error: "MoreThanTenPubWorkKeys                   extfld('MRTHANTEN');     
======>                                             aaaaaa                           
*RNF3701 20 a      013100  Keyword is not allowed for a subfield definition; keyword is ignored." Any way to declare in between?

Comment: `extfld()` can only be used in a DS that has `ext` and/or `extname()`

Comment: What I meant to say is, if I try to declare a subfield using extfld option AFTER the subfield using like keyword is declared, it fails compilation. i.e, the subfield using LIKE needs to be the last field of the DS. But I want to order the subfields by using the LIKE first followed by a subfield using EXTFIELD.

Comment: post a new question showing your problem

Comment: done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330006/defining-data-structure-using-extname-extfld-and-like